# Was there some deliberate significance to the number of divisions in the proposed post-WW2 joint communist-nationalist Chinese army being 108?

Tags: china

https://www.britannica.com/event/Chinese-Civil-War
(Search "108".)

It's a sacred number in the Dharmic religions, was the number of outlaws in The Water Margin, and  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/108_(number)) had some influence in martial arts in China given the buddhist aspect of their origins.

But I don't know if this is coincidental.

If it wasn't coincidental, why was 108 settled on?